# Don't add NULL data to the list

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, treeview

I have an object:

```
public class DataItem
{

    public string Location
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<PersonInfo> PersonList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class PersonInfo
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have some results from a table that return something like:

```
Room1 John
Room1 Jim
Room1 Dawn
Room1 Bob
Room1 Katie
Room2 <NULL>
Room3 <NULL>
Room4 <NULL>
Room5 <NULL>
```

I have some LINQ that I've written:

```
        var RoomData= from table in sqlResults.AsEnumerable()
                         group table by table["Room"] into groupby
                         select new TreeViewDataItem
                         {
                             RoomName = groupby.Key.ToString(),
                             PersonList = groupby.Select(row => new PersonInfo                                 {
                                 Name = row["PERSON"].ToString(),
                                 Id = row.Field<Int32?>("PERSONID")
                             }).ToList()
                         };
```

I'm loading a TreeView and this is working fine, but I'd like to eliminate the Expanders when the child record is NULL.

What do I need to do to not show null records in the Treeview?

Answer (score 0):

```
var RoomData= from table in sqlResults.AsEnumerable()
              group table by table["Room"] into groupby 
              from g in groupby
              where g.Any(row=>row["PERSON"] != null)                        
              select new TreeViewDataItem {
                     RoomName = g.Key.ToString(),
                     PersonList = g.Where(row=>row["PERSON"] != null)
                                   .Select(row => new PersonInfo{
                                     Name = row["PERSON"].ToString(),
                                     Id = row.Field<Int32?>("PERSONID")
                                    }).ToList()
              };
```